# Why is this activity missing its header?

Tags: android-studio

In android studio I see the header.

[image]

When I run the app, the header is missing!

[image]

I created an identical Activity, and the header is there.

I fixed the problem by just creating a new activity but I know it is not the right way to fix it. The activity xml is identical, so is the class. I am stumped and I want to understand why.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Please comment below if you want me to add some lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should check your styles. Be careful there is not NoActionBar. And also check your manifest.xml in application themes.

Comment: The answer was in AndroidManifest.xml. I had to remove some style that was added in there for some reason.